# How to remove git pull message from windows

Tags: git, bash, github

When I type `git pull origin master` on Ubuntu, it pulls the changes from the remote repository into my local repository, and it works fine.

However, if I do it on Windows (using git bash), it pulls the changes as a merge commit (as if I was accepting a pull request). So even if I'm just updating my local repository, next time I push it, the pull commit will be there.

Is there a way to remove this behaviour from Windows? I'd want it to be like Ubuntu, where pulling doens't cause a new commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git pull` equals `git fetch` plus `git merge` unless it is a fast forward, where the merge is not needed, or you have configured `pull.rebase=true`, in which case a rebase is done instead of a merge.

So there are two possibilities:

1. You have local commits in Windows but not in Ubuntu. Then, do a `git fetch` and optionally a `git rebase` (but be aware of the `rebase` rules!).
2. You have Ubuntu configured with `pull.rebase=true` but not Windows.

My advice anyway would be not to do `git pull`. Instead just do `git fetch` and from then on whatever you need.

PS: Something like this happened to me once, and it was because in Windows I had a couple of extra private commits (to adapt the project to Windows' quirkiness). So when doing a `git pull` those two commits where just in the middle. I did `git config pull.rebase true` and the problem was over.